# What SQL standard is Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hard time finding what SQL commands/syntax is available in Spark SQL. I usually end up finding a variety of Scala function calls.

What standard does Spark SQL comply to? Where can I find an official comprehensive list of the SQL supported by Spark?

To be clear, I am looking for the Spark SQL equivalent of this [List of PostgreSQL Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/blog/spark-sql-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not complete but Databricks has this... https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/index.html

That is the only pseudo official Spark SQL guide on the net.

Comment: Thanks. Does Spark SQL follow SQL standard closely? Which SQL is it close to, postgresql SQL, PL/pgSQL, mysql, TSQL, PL/SQL?

Comment: It's closest to Hive SQL.

Comment: The links given is now broken, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Latest Apache Spark documentation SQL:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref.html

Spark SQL Syntax:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: [That official page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-ref.html) is the best reference about Spark SQL in my opinion. From there you can also navigate to other interesting links.

To elaborate, Spark SQL has a dialect on its own, that is very close to HiveQL, though it is missing some features ([source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-migration-guide.html#compatibility-with-apache-hive)).

Regarding [SQL standard](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization), you can enable ANSI compliance in two different ways ([source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html)):

1. Set `spark.sql.ansi.enabled` to `true`
2. Set `spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy` to `ANSI`

Note : [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) is the most similar page to the PostgreSQL list you mentioned.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.